# Securely remove files from an NTFS drive?

Tags: external-disk, secure-erase

I have an external NTFS drive, and I want to securely remove some files from it. SRM is no longer available in Sierra. I tried to install SRM with Homebrew, and did install it successfully, but when I apply the command to an external drive I get an error: "Segmentation fault: 11" What can I do?

I do not use software like Paragon NTFS to enable write on the drive. Instead I do this in Terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line to nano, replacing “NAME” with the label of your NTFS drive:

```
LABEL=NAME none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then the Enter key, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close nano.

Comment: What software do you use to write to the NTFS drive?

Comment: Actually I don't use software. I did option 3 on this website: https://www.howtogeek.com/236055/how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-on-a-mac/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gshred. Install homebrew if not installed from www.brew.sh. Then do

```
brew install coreutils
```

to remove files, do

```
gshred -u <file1> <file2>
```

Comment: Is this secure removal? How many passes is it?

Comment: 3 by default. Check the parameters "man gshred". "-n N overwrite N times instead of the default (3)"

Comment: Well it is as secure removal as srm - good enough in most cases if the file  system  overwrites
       data  in  place.

Comment: If you need to remove "really" secure, overwrite the whole hard disk with random data. Never use tools on mounted filesystems. There are too many ways this can go wrong.

Comment: On current hard drives, a few passes are sufficient for high security wipes due to the high data density. Keep in mind that the drives have a lot of electronic inside that remaps data, so if you have _really really_ important data on the drive, you should really physically destroy it if you want to securely remove the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rm` with the `-P` option which will overwrite the file prior to deleting it.

From the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html):

> Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are overwritten
>   three times, first with the byte pattern 0xff, then 0x00, and then
>   0xff again, before they are deleted

It's not a DoD 7 pass wipe, but fairly secure nonetheless.  So, your command would be:

`rm -P /path/to/foo.bar`

And it will do a triple overwrite before removal.